# X11 Forwarding Error on Ubuntu, Though It Works On Windows

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I have an interesting issue - on Windows using **Xming** I can forward X11 requests to my client (PC) successfully and can run the applications. However, I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC and somehow I couldn't make it work.

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config has the following lines:

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
```

And I try connecting using the command:

```
ssh -X -v username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The verbose output shows me:

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

I have also executed `xhost +` to disable all access control on client, but the weird thing is on my client the `DISPLAY` variable is set to `:0` and I cannot replace it with anything else such as `localhost:0` or even `$Local_IP:0`, X11 won't work when I do that, see sample output below - I suspect this could lead to an answer:

```
koray@koray-Latitude:~$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0 # $localip:0 doesn't work either
koray@koray-Latitude:~$ emacs
Display localhost:0 unavailable, simulating -nw
koray@koray-Latitude:~$
```

Comment: Not really a programming question, try asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @user2062950 Thanks for redirecting, I've cloned it to SuperUser (http://superuser.com/questions/628480/x11-forwarding-error-on-ubuntu-client-though-it-works-on-windows) and let's keep this one for reference too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it - it was an **authentication** issue. Executing the following line on Server resolved the issue:

```
$ xauth add ${client_ip}:0 . ${hex_key}
xauth:  creating new authority file /homes/${username}/.Xauthority
```

where `${client_ip}` is the client with X server running, `${hex_key}` is the 32-character hex string. Afterwards upon assinging the `$DISPLAY` env variable I can now connect successfully.